# Failing to create a fat jar

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to use [Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) Gradle plugin to create a fat jar.

Part of my build.gradle.kts looks like this:

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}

group = "com.test"
version = "0.1"
application {
    mainClass.set("com.test.ApplicationKt")
}
```

Everything is good, but I want to include `.properties` files in the fat jar as well.

```
tasks {
    withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> { kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "17" } }

    named<com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar>("shadowJar") {
        archiveBaseName.set("shadow")
        mergeServiceFiles()
        manifest { attributes(mapOf("Main-Class" to "com.test.ApplicationKt")) }
//        include("*.properties")
    }
```

For some reason uncommenting the `include("*.properties")` statement above, makes my fat jar empty. I can build it ok with `./gradlew shadowJar` but when I try to run the jar with `java -jar` I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class...`

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

specify the main class name inside shadow task

```
tasks {
named<ShadowJar>("shadowJar") {
    archiveBaseName.set("shadow")
    mergeServiceFiles()
    manifest {
        attributes(mapOf("Main-Class" to "main-class-path"))
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working. The moment I add `include("*.properties")` to the shadow task, I start getting the same error `Could not find or load main class...`